# THREE JS converting to BufferGeometry from Geometry not working when loading PLY file

Tags: three.js, geometry, buffer-geometry

I am loading a very complex 3D model from a PLY file (over 60Mb). In my project I need to use the orbit-control to move around the object. Obviously due to the large file the operation is painfully slow in some couputers. In order to speed up things a bit I am trying to convert my geometry into a Buffer geometry with the following lines of code:

```
this.loader.load('assets/data/GuyFawkesMask.ply', function (geometry) {
      var bufferGeometry = new THREE.BufferGeometry().fromGeometry( geometry );

      console.log(bufferGeometry);

      // Create object
        let object =
            new THREE.Mesh(bufferGeometry,
            new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial(
                {
                    color: 0xFFFFFF,
                    //vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors,
                    shading: THREE.FlatShading,
                    shininess: 0
                })
            );

        _this.add(object);
    });
```

But I am getting the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
>           at DirectGeometry.fromGeometry (three.module.js:12219)
>           at BufferGeometry.fromGeometry (three.module.js:14307)
>           at threed-viewer.component.ts:379
>           at index.js:52
>           at XMLHttpRequest. (three.module.js:29263)
>           at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.818.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:367)
>           at Object.onInvokeTask (ng_zone.js:264)
>           at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.818.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:366)
>           at Zone.webpackJsonp.818.Zone.runTask (zone.js:166)
>           at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:420)

Any idea?

Thank you,

Dino

Comment: If I get it right, looking into the source code of `PLYLoader.js`, the `geometry`, which the callback function returns, is already of `THREE.BufferGeometry()`.

Comment: Gosh, you are right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just posting prisoner849 comment (as an answer) for future reference:

> If I get it right, looking into the source code of PLYLoader.js, the
>   geometry, which the callback function returns, is already of
>   THREE.BufferGeometry()